# put a value inside a custom Marker Google Map V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I work with Google Map v3 api and i have been searched how can i put a value in my marker.

firstly my data is in to database i loaded the data see the script as bellow

```
var locations = [            
            <?php foreach ($results as $val) : $v=addslashes($val["nomst"]) ?>        
            [<?="'$v'" ?>,<?= $val['Lat'] ?>,<?= $val['Lon'] ?>,<?= $val[$param] ?>],
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    ];


      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.975750, 10.669184),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
      }
```

secondly i created a loop to add my markers

```
 var marker, i;
            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    icon:'icon.png',
                    map: map
                });
```

i created a custom icon that i had in my folder and what i need is inside each icon i need to add a value that i have in my location array something like this 
`locations[i][3]`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom properties to a marker:

```
marker.my_prop = locations[i][3];
```

However take care when you do this. Markers contain undocumented properties whose names can and do change. You'll want to make certain that you choose a property name that will not collide with a private marker property.